# How to specify a domain name to Yii 2 baseurl

Tags: php, yii2, base-url

This is a question about Yii 2. I have already done this for Yii 1.x (previous versions), but Yii 2 seems quite different.

For a static web site, I need to set my base URL to `http://www.sampledomain.com`
I understand that default server name can be used. However I'd like to hard code my domain name to some one place in the framework.

In my /config/web.php (config file). I have this configuration.

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
...
```

Currently `Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl` returns and empty.

If this is all about setting and getting Yii baseurl. Could anyone please help by showing me how the code above can change, so I can set the base URL to http://www.sampledomain.com
At the moment, a Yii 2 static site takes the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] of the domain, so it uses the domain being visited. However if my static site has several parked domains, I want all my internal links within the website to use one domain only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In params.php
add

```
return [
.....,
    'domainName' => 'yourDomani.com',
]
```

and in controller you can call it by

```
Yii::$app->params['domainName'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, That fulfills the requirement and I just started to implement like that. However I'm expecting an answer for the yii baseurl confusion I'm having.